# Why is Usagi both Sailor Moon and Princess Serenity?

Tags: sailor-moon

Usagi is first awakened as Sailor Moon in the first episode.
Later, it is revealed that she is actually Princess Serenity from the Moon and awakened when Endymion is in danger.
Why is she **both**?
Sailor Mars, Sailor Venus, Sailor Mercury and Sailor Jupiter exist to protect Princess Serenity and their corresponding home planet.
However, Sailor Moon does not make sense in that constellation since she is Princess Serenity.

Why does Sailor Moon exist when Princess Serenity is a thing?
Is it ever explained why/how Sailor Moon became a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are speaking about the past Princess Serenity, then this [tumblr page](https://silvermoon424.tumblr.com/post/97346293538/sailor-venus-the-leader) speaking about why Sailor Venus is the leader, answers the question of why Usagi is Sailor Moon.

There are images of the manga where Luna mentions Usagi was developed into Sailor Moon to better protect her and hide her from the enemies...hide who she really is, the reincarnation of Princess Serenity.

If it's also in relation to the future Princess Serenity, all of the essence and powers of Princess Serenity is latent inside Usagi/Sailor Moon which is awakened at some point, so she is able to exist as both from there on.

Comment: does it mean everyone can become a sailor soldier?

Comment: oh, good question. I'm curious now where the brooch came from if it didn't exist before, so I would assume.

Comment: I only watched the 90s anime, but in it, I think it was mentioned that the Sailor Soldiers are/were inhabitants of their respective planet. In Sailor Moon Stars, Galaxia is searching for Star Seeds, which only Sailor Soldiers have. If everyone can be a Sailor Soldier by using a brooch, that concept of star seeds does not work out.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research, I couldn't find any cases where either the manga or the anime formally explain the origin of Sailor Moon. However, there are a couple theories we can create based on what we do know.

*Theory 1: Giving Usagi the brooch was the only thing in Luna's power to protect her from the various attacks coming her way.*

In episode 1, Luna tells her to transform in order to save her best friend's shop. There's no real explanation of why Usagi is able to use it. We don't know if, like the other Sailor Scouts, it belongs to her, or if the brooch is one could work for anyone who says the commands. Since the power of Princess Serenity needed to be unlocked by Usagi herself, without her memories she was completely defenseless against the dark forces coming her way. Sailor Moon could have been *Luna's* best chance at protecting Usagi until she recognized her identity.

*Theory 2: Sailor Moon was created because Princess Serenity felt powerless in her previous life.*

In episode 35, Usagi recalls her memories as Princess Serenity in which she went from having everything she wanted to losing everyone she loves.  One could assume that she felt powerless about the situation and wished she could have protected her loved ones.  Sailor Moon could have been an alter ego that Princess Serenity wish she had that she was able to assume in her next life. It could also be why whenever she's backed in a corner (especially where Tuxedo Mask is concerned), Sailor Moon transforms in Princess Serenity who is the person who always wanted to save him.